# Cucumber Dependency Issue - couldn't load plugin class

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I am new in cucumber extendable code I need to help. I am using java 8 and maven and want to generate cucumber extendable report. But Every time I am getting below error:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Couldn't load plugin class: com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter. It does not implement cucumber.api.Plugin
```

The Pom.xml file is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>CucumberFramwork</groupId>
    <artifactId>ExtendReport</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>ExtendReport</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Runner Class Code:

```
package runners;

import java.io.File;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import com.cucumber.listener.Reporter;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/functionalTests", 
                 glue = { "stepDefinitions" },
                 plugin = {
        "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/cucumber-reports/report.html" }, 
                 monochrome = true)
public class TestRunner {
    @AfterClass
    public static void writeExtentReport() {
        try {

                    Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("C:\\Software\\WprkSpace\\ExtendReport\\Configs\\extent-config.xml"));
        }
     catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Reporter.loadXMLConfig("/ExtendReport/Configs/extent-config.xml");
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Couldn't load plugin class: com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter. It does not implement cucumber.api.Plugin
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.loadClass(PluginFactory.java:178)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.pluginClass(PluginFactory.java:165)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.getPluginClass(PluginFactory.java:222)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.isStepDefinitionReporterName(PluginFactory.java:205)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions$ParsedPluginData.addPluginName(RuntimeOptions.java:357)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.parse(RuntimeOptions.java:159)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:90)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:85)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptionsFactory.create(RuntimeOptionsFactory.java:23)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:56)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this 2 dependencies **with the same versions** below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
   </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
   </dependency>
```

More information here:

[extent-report-plugin-for-cucumber](https://www.axelerant.com/resources/team-blog/setup-for-selenium-with-cucumber-using-maven)

Answer (score 1):

**POM Analysis Says -**

- You are keeping different libraries of extent to create the report which is not advisable & expected. We shall use specific set of these depending on the requirement not all together.
- You are using pretty old dependency(**info.cukes v1.2.5**) of Cucumber
- Your pom.xml is having direct & transitive dependencies together

**First** Let's have basic understanding of these libraries to create extent report

**1. Vimal Selvam Library:** Below is the required maven dependency and a sample test to demonstrate how configuration set up is done.

**Maven Dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Please note that **Java 8+** and adding the dependency of **ExtentReport v3.1.1+** is mandatory.To do that, paste the following in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Cucumber Runner File**

```
 @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(
            features = {"src/test/resources/features"},
            glue = {"com.cucumber.stepdefinitions"},
            plugin = {"com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:output/report.html"}
            )
    public class RunCukesTest {
        @AfterClass
        public static void teardown() {
            Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("src/test/resources/extent-config.xml"));
            Reporter.setSystemInfo("user", System.getProperty("user.name"));
            Reporter.setSystemInfo("os", "Mac OSX");
            Reporter.setTestRunnerOutput("Sample test runner output message");
        }
    }
```

The above setup will generate the report in output directory with the name of report.html.

**2. Extent Adapter:** Beauty is, you do not need to write any code any where to generate report this way except from setting adapter in runner below.

**Maven Dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Add the **com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter plugin** to the runner.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"})
public class RunCukesTest {
    // ..
}
```

**Report Output Directory** - ../Project Directory/test-output/HtmlReport

**Key Point:** We shall not mix direct & transitive dependencies specially their versions! Doing so can cause unpredictable outcome. We would request you to use **Cucumber v>=4.0.0** as you are using pretty old dependency(**v1.2.5**) of Cucumber.

**First** You can add below set of cucumber minimal dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Second** Adding below extent dependency under POM.XML** considering the case not using extent adapter.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

In this workflow, **Do not Add the com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter plugin to the runner**.

As last **Hooks class** where we do write extent code which gets executed for each scenario.

public class Hooks {

```
private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Hooks.class);
static volatile int x = 0;

@Before
public void setUpScenario(Scenario scenario){
    ExtentTestManager.startTest("Scenario No . " + (x = x + 1) + " : " + scenario.getName());
    ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO, "Scenario No . "+ x + " Started : - " + scenario.getName());
}

@After
public void afterScenario(Scenario scenario){
    String videoFile= Utility.stopAUTTestRecorder();
    try{
        if(scenario.isFailed()){
           ExtentTestManager.addScreenShotsOnFailure();
            //------------------------- Attaching video in the Report -------------------------
            String failedTestVideo = "<a href=\"" + videoFile + "\">Download Failed Test Case Video</a>";
            ExtentTestManager.embedVideoLink(failedTestVideo);
            //scenario.write(failedTestVideo);
        }
        }
        ExtentManager.getReporter().flush();
    }
  }
```